# PyCharm type-hinting warning

Tags: python, pycharm, warnings, type-hinting

Using Python 2.7 and PyCharm CE 2018.2.4, I have the following code:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt

def updateGroupDynamicBenchmark(self, security, group, runTime):
    """
    Update all the fields in a group from BPipe
    :param security: Security to update
    :type  security: Common.secMasterRecords.SecMasterRecord
    :param group:    Group id to update
    :type  group:    Common.secMasterFieldPolicyMgr.SecMasterFieldGroup
    :param runTime:   Running time for the update
    :type  runTime:   datetime.datetime
    :return:  New expiry time
    :rtype:   datetime.datetime
    """
    return dt.now()
```

This code generates a warning, appearing on the name of the function in the declaration:

> Type hinting is missing for a function definition

What could be done to fix this? Thank you very much

Comment: This inspection is about type hints in [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) form.

Comment: @user2235698 I understand, but I thought one should be able to supply type hints in either convention

Comment: Such an ability was discussed internally in PyCharm team, could you please file an issue in our [tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY)?

Answer (score 0):

Typehint your function.

Example:

```
def square(number: int) -> int:
    return number ** 2
```

Comment: why doesn't the standard type hinting mechanism work here? It works on almost all other functions in the same file?

Comment: Oh I overlook that you specify the type in the pydoc. That might be pycharm issue.